# Cycle Count Calculation in PIC

Tags: pic

You are given a subroutine written for a PIC16F877 working at 4MHz to
obtain an approximate 30ms delay.

```
1 COUNTER1 equ 0x20
2 COUNTER2 equ 0x21
3
4 delay_loop:
5
6 movlw d'30'
7 movwf COUNTER2
8
9 ; Loop1 body takes about 1ms
10 LOOP1:
11 movlw d'200'
12 movwf COUNTER1
13
14 ; Loop2 body takes about 5us
15 LOOP2:
16 nop
17 nop
18 decfsz COUNTER1, F
19 goto LOOP2
20
21 decfsz COUNTER2, F
22 goto LOOP1
23 return

Instruction Cycles
movlw          1
movwf          1
 nop           1
decfsz         1*
goto           1
return         2
```

Well, I could not end up with same values in lines 9 and 14. Can you, please, show me the detailed calculations?

Comment: This online PIC12F simulator might be useful for seeing how the chip steps through the code. Cycle count is shown at the bottom of the simulator box: http://www.microcontrollerjs.com/sim/microcontroller.html?file=flash.asm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your instruction cycles are not correct. A `GOTO` is two cycles and `DECFSZ` is either one or two cycles depending on the result.

So, for `LOOP2`:

```
LOOP2:
    nop                  ; 1 cycle
    nop                  ; 1 cycle
    decfsz COUNTER1, F   ; 1 cycle except at loop end, then 2 cycles
    goto LOOP2           ; 2 cycles
```

So the total is 5 cycles, which with a 4MHz clock having a 1us cycle time<sup>1</sup> is 5us. With `COUNTER1` being 200, that inner loop takes 200 * 5us = 1000us = 1ms.

Now the enclosing loop, `LOOP1`:

```
LOOP1:
    movlw d'200'         ; 1 cycle
    movwf COUNTER1       ; 1 cycle

    ; 1ms delay from LOOP2 (removed for clarity)

    decfsz COUNTER2, F   ; 1 cycle except at loop end, then 2 cycles
    goto LOOP1           ; 2 cycles
    return               ; 2 cycles
```

So a total of 5 cycles for the LOOP1 housekeeping (ignoring the final RETURN), added to the 1000us from the inner loop = 1005us. With `COUNTER2` being 30, the total delay is 30 * 1005us = 30.15ms (give or take the handful of initial housekeeping instructions and the final return, but you get the idea).

<sup>1</sup>Remember that these PICs use 4 clock cycles per instruction, so a 4MHz clock executes at 1MIPs, giving an instruction time of 1us.