# How to calculate number of instruction cycles?

Tags: assembly, delay, pic, cpu-cycles

What is the number of instruction cycles for `EastLoop` block? I have the following code:

```
   #include 
   __config (_INTRC_OSC_NOCLKOUT & _WDT_OFF & _MCLRE_OFF)

   cblock 0x20
Delay1
Delay2
Delay3
    endc

    org 0
Start:
    bsf       STATUS,RP0
    clrf      TRISIO
    bcf       STATUS,RP0
    clrf       Delay1
    clrf       Delay2
    clrf       Delay3
    movlw     0xD0
    movwf     B'100000'
    movlw     .7
    movwf     CMCON
MainLoop:
    bsf       GPIO,GP1
    bsf       0x21,5
EastLoop:
    nop
    decfsz    Delay1,f
    goto      EastLoop
    decfsz    Delay2,f
    goto      EastLoop
    movwf     Delay3
    bcf       0x05,1
    bsf       0x05,4
    decf      Delay3,0
    bsf       0x20,7
    bsf       0x20,3
    bsf       O'40',1
    comf      .32,1
NordLoop:
    decfsz    Delay1,f
    goto      NordLoop
    btfsc     GPIO,GP1
    goto      SetStep
    bsf       GPIO,GP1
    goto      SetSStep
SetStep:
    bcf       GPIO,GP1
SetSStep:
    decfsz    Delay3,f
    goto      NordLoop
    bcf       0x05,1
    bcf       0x05,4
    end
```

Could someone please explain this?

Comment: The number of instruction cycles would depend on the contents of the memory locations named `Delay1` and `Delay2`.  The code you posted defines where those locations are, but doesn't store any values into them, so no exact answer to your question can be given.

Comment: @jasonharper What about now? I'm new to this, so I don't exactly know what you mean, but I added the rest of the code I had but thought I didn't need.

Comment: Labels just identify one single point in the code (or data), so  proper analysis requires a specific understanding of what is meant by the word block there, and there are several posible interpretations, so without clarification is ambiguous.

Comment: Don't edit your question to remove necessary parts of the code for it to make sense and be answerable.

Answer (score 2):

The processor executes assembly instructions in different instruction cycles (according to the complexity of the instruction). You can learn about instruction cycles by reading [the datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/41190G.pdf). The total number of instruction cycles is the sum of all instruction cycles according to the program logic. According to the datasheet, the instruction cycles of some of the commands above are as follows:

| Mnemonic | Cycles |
| --- | --- |
| NOP | 1 |
| DECFSZ | 1 (2) * |
| GOTO | 2 |
| MOVWF | 1 |
| BCF | 1 |
| BSF | 1 |
| DECF | 1 |
| COMF | 1 |

(*) `DECFSZ` → If the result is 0, then a `NOP` is executed instead, making it a `2 TCY` instruction.

### Related Links

- [Cycle Count Calculation in PIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377875/cycle-count-calculation-in-pic)
- [Understanding timing and delays on the PIC18F4620](https://robosumo.wordpress.com/2013/03/26/understanding-timing-and-delays-on-the-pic18f4620/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are working with MPLABx. In this case you could count the number of instruction cycles with the stopwatch of the simulator:

- put the PC at the top of `Eastloop`
- start the stopwatch and reset it to zero
- step thru the loop and the cycles will be count